# Hosting MSMQ Integration Binding with WAS

Tags: wcf, hosting

Appears that WAS does not support the integration binding.  I've tried setting it up by enabling the net.msmq protocol in WAS just to confirm it to no avail.  Has anyone gotten this to work and if not, what are you using to host integration services?  I'm leaning towards a Windows Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work.  The messages stay in the queue and never get removed.  We'll use a Windows Service to host the binding.